# React Native Maps and React Native Map Clustering

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have used react native maps and react native map clustering to show GEO locations on my map view, And its working fine when my targeted SDK version is 23, But when I tried to publish it on play-store it doesn't allow me to publish the application because of that I have used targeted SDK version(23), After that I have changed the SDK version in to 26 Play-store allow me to publish my application.

After changing the targeted SDK version into 26 the Markers are not showing on my map view, clustering is working fine and also the pins, But not the markers with images.

If I make the SDK version into 23(21,22) it works fine, but not with the SDK version 23(24,25,26), Can someone help me on this?